# Symfony2 cannot render template inside Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following structure:

```
/src/Product/AdminBundle/Resources/views/main.twig
```

I am trying to render this template from controller:

```
$this->render(...);
```

or from routing.yml

```
index_page:
    path: /
    defaults:
         _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
         template: ...
```

How can I render this from from inside the controller in the bundle? Here is what I have tried with no luck:

- Product:AdminBundle:main.twig
- ProductAdminBundle:main.twig
- @ProductAdminBundle:main.twig
- @ProductAdminBundle/main.twig
- ProductAdminBundle/main.twig
- ProductAdminBundle/Resources/views/main.twig
- Product/AdminBundle/Resources/views/main.twig
- AdminBundle:main.twig
- AdminBundle/main.twig

Answer (score 5):

The usual path syntax is:

```
BundleName:DirectoryInView:file.html.twig
```

In your case, this will be:

```
ProductAdminBundle::main.html.twig
```

We use `::`, because your view is located in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

After trying every possible combination this is the one that worked for me:

```
@AdminBundle/Resources/views/main.twig
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
return $this->render('ProductAdminBundle:main.html.twig', []);
```

Where `main.html.twig` is your view name (and not main.twig).

Comment: Changed the name and even tried to add it to a directory to be sure. Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

AdminBundle::main.twig does not work

rename main.twig into main.html.twig

After that AdminBundle::main.html.twig will work!